# CREATE INDEX on wp_options / Will this have any negative effects?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

My server was running very slow, its a wordpress website with 50k members. I done some research and found my wp_options had over 800k rows, mainly due to transients and old plugin data, I cleaned up the expired transients and old plugin data and found no difference, In Fact there was still 300k rows.

I heard about adding an index to the wp_options table, so I thought I would give it a go. So i backed up my database and run the following query;

```
CREATE INDEX wp_options_autoload ON wp_options (autoload)
```

my page load time went from 8 seconds down to 2! It seams to have worked a dream! I'm so happy because its been a dark shadow for a while now.

the question is, will it have any negative effects on my wordpress site?

Comment: Something doesn't adds up here. what query (that went from 8 seconds to 2) do you run against the table? what is the size of the table?

Comment: If you've created a single index, there are no substantial contraindications .. the only side effect is that each time you entered, modified and deleted rows in a tavoel will be also updated the index .. if it's just one (or a few) is nothing perceptible seen in the number of rows